# Workaround for database changed from outside Event/Listener

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, filesystemwatcher, system.data.sqlite

As I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407195/does-entity-framework-system-data-sqlite-provide-a-database-changed-from-outsi) there is no technique built into SQLite to track database changes from somewhere else.  This problem is to be solved in C#.

I need this feature so, I am thinking about workarounds.

I thought I could add a [listener for the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721714/notification-when-a-file-changes), that gets informed, when the `.sqlite` file gets changed.  Has anybody solved this problem the same or another way or is there a better solution?

Comment: why have you not don a search on how to use [SQLite sqlCacheDependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768592/update-c-sharp-client-whenever-database-is-updated) look at the Accepted answer here for how you can do what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8993989/sql-dependency-in-c-sharp

Comment: @DJKRAZE I have. But I only get answers saying that SqlCacheDependency is not supported by SQLite. [Like in the answer to my previous question.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14407273/433718) I only found [an article from 2004](http://blog.csdn.net/waterboy/article/details/164692) that is using Polling and constructs a SqlCacheDependency object, when new changes were found. But I am not looking for a polling based solution. A listener for the file system appears to me the better solution than polling.